# Trying to return array of objects from async function, array returned undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I've been working on a scraper function.

Now about the app: there are two scrapers, that scrape data about apartments from two pages. Now when data is finished scraping it's been passed to `mergeData` function, where the goal is to merge all the arrays of objects, that are passed from scrapers - into one single array with all objects from the scrapers, and then to be passed to insert function, to be inserted into the DB.

Now here is one of the scrapers

```
const data_functions = require('../data-functions/data-functions');
const axios = require('axios'); //npm package - promise based http client
const cheerio = require('cheerio'); //npm package - used for web-scraping in server-side implementations

//santScaper function which as paramater needs count which is sent in the scraping-service file.
exports.santScraper = async (count) => {
  const url = `https://www.sant.ba/pretraga/prodaja-1/tip-2/cijena_min-20000/stranica-${count}`;

  const santScrapedData = [];
  try {
    load_url(url, santScrapedData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Function that does loading URL part of the scraper, and starting of process for fetching raw data.
const load_url = async (url, santScrapedData) => {
  await axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    fetch_raw_html($).each((index, element) => {
      process_single_article($, index, element, santScrapedData);
    });

    data_functions.mergeData(santScrapedData); <- here is data passed into the mergeData component
  });
};

//Part where raw html data is fetched but in div that we want.
const fetch_raw_html = ($) => {
  return $('div[class="col-xxs-12 col-xss-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4"]');
};

//Here is all logic for getting data that we want, from the raw html.
const process_single_article = ($, index, element, santScrapedData) => {
  const getLink = $(element).find('a[class="re-image"]').attr('href');
  const getDescription = $(element).find('a[class="title"]').text();
  const getPrice = $(element)
    .find('div[class="prices"] > h3[class="price"]')
    .text()
    .replace(/\.| ?KM$/g, '')
    .replace(',', '.');
  const getPicture = $(element).find('img').attr('data-original');
  const getSquaremeters = $(element)
    .find('span[class="infoCount"]')
    .first()
    .text()
    .replace(',', '.')
    .split('m')[0];
  const pricepersquaremeter =
    parseFloat(getPrice) / parseFloat(getSquaremeters);

  santScrapedData[index] = {
    id: getLink.substring(42, 46),
    link: getLink,
    description: getDescription,
    price: Math.round(getPrice),
    picture: getPicture,
    squaremeters: Math.round(getSquaremeters),
    pricepersquaremeter: Math.round(pricepersquaremeter),
  };
};
```

Now the `mergeData` component

```
let mergedApartments = [];
exports.mergeData = async (apartments) => {
  //Fetching all apartments that are passed from scraper(s)
  mergedApartments = mergedApartments.concat(apartments);
  //Sending data for validation to the validation function
  return mergedApartments;
};
this.mergeData().then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Now this returns `[undefined]`, where I expected to be populated with objects from two scrapers.

Now what I want: The one scraper return ~9 objects in the array, while the second scraper returns ~30 objects in the array. Now I want these two arrays that are coming into the function, to be merged and passed as one array with objects(so `mergedApartments.length` would be ~39. And I can't achieve that, I've tried many solutions from other questions, but no success.

What right solution would be? Thanks!

Comment: `this.mergeData().then((result) => console.log(result));` - this string called BEFORE your srcap functions (when you require this module). Here you add `undefined` value (empty function argument) to your accumulate array and post this array to console. No wonder that you see `[undefined]`. Try to post console log AFTER you scrap functions finish

Comment: Thank you, makes a lot of sense! So, how exactly function will know if the scrapers are finished their jobs?

Comment: There are many options for this, for example you can use native js `Promise.all`, or count your callback calls, or use [native node events functional](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/events.html#events_emitter_listenercount_eventname), or use special package like `async`, `bluebird` or `deferred` etc

Comment: Thank you very much. I will explore `bluebird`. Also, if u could throw in some example that already done something like mine example, or how you would deal with this problem, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Your data module:
const data_functions = {
  mergedApartments: [],
  mergeData(apartments){ this.mergedApartments.push(...apartments) },
};

// Scrape mock: async function, returning array of data
const load_url = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve([1,2,3,4]), 2000));

// scraper 1:
const santScraper = async () => {
  const data = await load_url(); // Imagine here all operations for scraping data till you have array..
  data_functions.mergeData(data);
  return data;
};

// scraper 2:
const anotherScraper = async () => {
  const data = await load_url(); // Imagine here all operations for scraping data till you have array..
  data_functions.mergeData(data);
  return data;
};


// Call both scrapers, await them and get all in one array:
Promise.all([santScraper(), anotherScraper()])
  .then(() => console.log(data_functions.mergedApartments))
```